# Setting SSH tunnel on pivotal cloudfoundry for remote debugging

Tags: cloud-foundry

Does anyone have an idea on steps of setting up an SSH tunnel for the CloudFoundry? I want to do remote debugging on cloud, but am blocked behind a firewall. So need to setup an SSH tunnel for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote [a blog post on setting up remote debugging for Java apps](http://mikusa.blogspot.com/2014/08/debugging-java-applications-on.html) on Cloud Foundry.  It covers using an SSH Tunnel to work around a firewall / NAT.

The answer from the article is this...

1. Obtain a public server.
2. Install SSHD. Edit `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, add or set `GatewayPorts` to `yes`. Restart SSHD.
3. On your local machine run `ssh -f -N -T -R 0.0.0.0:<public-port>:127.0.0.1:<debugger-port> <user>@<public-server-ip>` (Windows users can use cygwin or possibly Putty, although the command will be different). This will instruct SSH to connect to the remote host, setup a reverse tunnel and go into the background. The reverse tunnel will listen on your public server on the port you specify (i.e. public-port) and forward traffic to the debugger port on your local machine. You can use different port numbers, but it is easiest if you just use the same port.
4. Start the debugger and listen on the same port (i.e. debugger-port) that you used in the SSH command.
5. Edit your `manifest.yml` file. Set `JAVA_OPTS` to `-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=<your-ip>:<your-port>`.
6. Run cf push.

For a gentler walk through, see the post.